# Segfault when lua_newtable called 100 times in a row

Tags: lua, segmentation-fault, lua-api

When I'm trying to add 100 tables in Lua c stack, I receive segfault on function end.

Code example:

lua_example.c: http://pastebin.com/GFvLwMY2

Makefile: http://pastebin.com/3EWJiVz7

test.lua: http://pastebin.com/1y22XvzK

Maybe I'm doing it wrong? What setting I should increase to be able to add 100 tables?

local variables limit is 200 by default, registers limit is 254, so I don't get it.

```
static int lua_example_test( lua_State *L ) {
    for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
        lua_newtable(L);
    }
    return 100;
}
```

I've tried lua-5.2.4 and lua-5.3.2, problem occurs in both of them.

Comment: See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.2. Instead of `lua_checkstack()`, you often want the variant that raises an error: [`luaL_checkstack()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_checkstack).

Comment: Did you invoke `luaL_checkstack` to make sure Lua C API stack is large enough to store 100 items?

Comment: @siffiejoe, Egor Skriptunoff, thanks! After wrapping in lua_checkstack, all works perfectly even with 1000+ tables, it grows the stack, didn't know about it.